# How to backup MySQL database on a remote server?

Tags: mysql, database, backup, remote-server, database-restore

I have a MySQL database existing on a remote server. I only have [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) connection privilege. I don't have FTP access to the server, and I need to do a complete dump of the database. I have tried `mysqldump`, but the issue is that it is creating the output on the server and as I don't have FTP I can not get the output from the server.

How can I do a clean backup and get the dump in my local machine(of course, the backup should be restored in my local machine)?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. `mysqldump` writes the dump to standard output, and when you redirect it it goes to the local host, not the server.

Comment: for running mysqldump i need to first login to the server, which I dont have the privilage, what I have is only a sql connection to the Mysql server

Comment: `mysqldump` takes a `--host` option to access a remote server, just like the `mysql` command does.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can specify the server name as an option to `mysqldump`:

```bsh
mysqldump --host servername dbname > dbname.sql
```

Comment: I used it many times, but was always wondering - isn't that a horrible exploit ? I mean, anyone with a host and a db name can copy a whole DB without any password ??

Comment: It checks permissions just like any other use of `mysql`.

Comment: There could be a firewall blocking network connections to the server. Or maybe it's configured to only listen on `localhost`. @guitarlass

Answer (score 28):

```
mysqldump --host hostaddress -P portnumber -u username -ppassword dbname > dbname.sql
```

Normally the remote port of MySQL is 3306. Here is an example:

```
mysqldump --host 192.168.1.15 -P 3306 -u dev -pmjQ9Y mydb > mydb.sql
```

Comment: One gotcha -be sure  NO space after the -p PASSWORD

Comment: man mysqldump: ... Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MySQL workbench http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/, which can backup directly to a local folder through a user-friendly interface

Comment: And, if you have only SSH access to the server, Workbench will work too. And it's available on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench`.

Comment: that soft is garbage, I been using it for years, you always get versions issues

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump.exe` locks tables by default, so other SQL actions are not possible during a dump. Without locking any tables, use the following syntax to backup a complete remote db and dump everything on your local machine:

```
mysqldump -u username -p --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false -h ipaddress myDB > backup.sql
```

Change `username` into your own username, change `ipaddress` into the remote ip address, and `myDB` to the actual database you want to backup. This will prompt you for your password. Once provided, the dump starts.

Answer (score 0):

I use SQLyog for this where we can connect to the remote server and take a back up with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

If the server admits PHP, you can upload and try [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/). I like it as a PHPMyAdmin replacer, and you can create backups with it!